# How many hosts can an IPv4 /22 network handle at most?

Tags: networking, ip

This came up in a test question and I would like to know the real answer as the possible choices confuse me.

**How many hosts can a network handle at the most, based on the following address: 135.46.56.0/22**

A: 1024, B: 1023, C: 1022, D: other

So if I'm not mistaken, /22 is 1024 (2^10) hosts. However, I'm not sure if network and broadcast address should be taken into consideration. I have the big book of networking by Tanenbaum and the example shown there doesn't exclude either one. I have an app on my phone that does this calculation and it points out the usable number of IP addresses is 1022 (google also found a claculator that said the usable number was 1023).

Could someone clear this up for me?

Comment: Are you a CCNA student? because that comes pretty well explained in your course's docs you know.

Comment: @arielnmz I'm a university student, and I had to google what CCNA stands for, so no, I'm not a CCNA student :)

Comment: CCNA is a networking course by Cisco, many schools have it available that's why I was wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For most (if not all) real-world scenarios he answer is **C: 1022 addresses**.

In theory you could use all 1024 addresses. But [RFC 919](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc919) explains why you should reserve two addresses for special purposes: **broadcast to all hosts** and **addressing the network itself**.

You could choose any two addresses to be these special addresses, but *If different IP implementations are to be compatible, there must be a distinguished number to denote "all hosts".* (RFC 919, section 7).

The RFC concludes with this nice summary:

> If the use of "all ones" in a field of an IP address means
> "broadcast", using "all zeros" could be viewed as meaning
> "unspecified".  There is probably no reason for such addresses to
> appear anywhere but as the source address of an ICMP Information
> Request datagram.  However, as a notational convention, we refer to
> networks (as opposed to hosts) by using addresses with zero fields.
> For example, 36.0.0.0 means "network number 36" while 36.255.255.255
> means "all hosts on network number 36".

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing

Yes.  `(addr)/22` = 1024 addresses, with traditionally one reserved for broadcast, and one reserved for the network itself.

Comment: Don't you mean C which is 1022 (1024-2)? D is for other.

Comment: @romeozor: oops, you're right